# Не удаётся попасть на виртуальную машину

Tags: ubuntu, безопасность, ssh

Сменил ноутбук, теперь не могу зайти на виртуальную машину.

```
ssh root@1.2.3.4
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed for RSA "" from agent: agent refused operation
root@1.2.3.4: Permission denied (publickey).
```

На другие машины доступ остался, проверял, перед тем как менять.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/your-key
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*
```